# Let Z , W , U , V complex numbers. Prove $|Z|+|U|+|V|+|W| ≤ |Z+U|+|Z+V|+|Z+W|+|U+V|+|U+W|+|V+W|$

Tags: complex-numbers

Let   z , w , u , v complex numbers. Prove

$|z|+|u|+|v|+|w| ≤ |z+u|+|z+v|+|z+w|+|u+v|+|u+w|+|v+w|$

My try:
$2z = (z+w) − (w+v) + (v+z)$

$2w= (w+u) −  (u+z) + (z+w)$

$2u = (u+w) − (w+v) + (v+u)$

$2v = (v+u) − (u+z) + (z+v)$

But I don't knew what next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By triangle inequality, we have
\begin{align}
2|z|&=|2z|\leq |z+w|+|w+v|+|v+z| \\
2|w|&=|2w|\leq |w+u|+|u+z|+|z+w| \\
&...
\end{align}
and add up these 4 inequalities.

Comment: An intermediate expression is maybe interesting in $2|z|=|2z|=|(z+w)+(-w-v)+(v+z)| \leq |z+w|+|w+v|+|v+z| $ for a better understanding.